# Arduino OLED ssd1315 graphic print questions

Tags: arduino-uno, oled

[image][image]I’ve tried to create a system that the rotary sensor as an input and use a 0.96 inch Oled as an output (first pic), try to show the voltage measurements and performance test using a small bar graphic.

And I use this code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SSD1306 Display(OLED_RESET);

int r = 0;
int i = 0;

void setup()   {


  Display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);  // initialize with the I2C addr 0x3C (for the 128x32)

  // i'll follow the license agreement and display the Adafruit logo
  // and since they were nice enough to supply the libraries
  Display.clearDisplay();
  Display.display();
  delay (1000);

  DrawTitles();

}


void loop() {

  // get some dummy data to display


  r = rand() / 220;
  //r = analogRead(ADJ_PIN);
  //r = r / 7.98;

  Display.setTextSize(2);
  // note set the background color or the old text will still display
  Display.setTextColor(WHITE, BLACK);
  Display.setCursor(0, 33);
  Display.println(Format(r * 7.99 / 204.6, 3, 2));

  //draw the bar graph
  Display.fillRect(r, 50, 128 - r, 10, BLACK);
  Display.fillRect(3, 50, r, 10, WHITE);

  for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    Display.fillRect(i * 10, 50, 2, 10, BLACK);
  }

  // now that the display is build, display it...
  Display.display();


}


void DrawTitles(void) {

  Display.setTextSize(2);
  Display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  Display.setCursor(0, 0);
  Display.println("Bar Graph");

  Display.setTextSize(1);
  Display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  Display.setCursor(0, 19);
  //Display.println("Measured Volts");
  Display.println("Random number");
  Display.display();

}


String Format(double val, int dec, int dig ) {

  // this is my simple way of formatting a number
  // data = Format(number, digits, decimals) when needed

  int addpad = 0;
  char sbuf[20];
  String fdata = (dtostrf(val, dec, dig, sbuf));
  int slen = fdata.length();
  for ( addpad = 1; addpad <= dec + dig - slen; addpad++) {
    fdata = " " + fdata;
  }
  return (fdata);

}
```

But it only showed the graphic bar and random number without an actual graphic bar at the end, so just wondered if I did something wrong or forgot to add something on my cold?

I'm new to this and I've tried so many things to fix it but seen not any of them working.

Thanks

Comment: please add a picture of the OLED output ... also add a drawing of the desired output

Comment: I've just add a picture

Comment: `But it only showed the graphic bar and random number`  ... where are those in the picture? ... all I see is text "Bar Graph" and "Random number"

Comment: we still do not know what you are trying to display

Comment: like the first picture, that's the one i trying to do.

Comment: What resolution does your display have? I think your display has a lower vertical resolution than the one in the first picture and assumed in your code. The value and bar graph are not displayed because they are drawn outside of the display's vertical boundary.